# Google Places Autocomplete Not Searching Address

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-autocomplete

I'm using google autocomplete in my application for address search. I'm typing my address but results are not found for it **mitskevichi 14**. But if I go to google maps website and type same address there, result is found.

I've tried, **mitskevichi 14** with any possible setups for

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

and

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

and couldn't get any results. When I try

https://www.google.com/maps

I Get results.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Here is my sample

```
var Autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('GoogleAutocomplete'));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/b4nz6Lk5/3/

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: "Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object, so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the bounds option in the request." - meaning you won't get results that are not on the currently displayed portion of the map. The result you are getting on Maps is in Tibilisi, Georgia, not Sydney...

Comment: I don't have map on my page at all, just plain textbox.

Comment: I don't see that anywhere in your description. Please provide us a way to test/debug your code.

Comment: I put the link to jsfiddle

Comment: The autocomplete component only matches full text, so "mitskevichi street #17" will match, "mitskevichi #17" will not. You need to look into the geocoding APIs if you need partial/fuzzy matching (like the Maps app does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I used two type of google services:

```
var Service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var Request = { input: "mitskevichi 14", language:'en', types: ['geocode'] };
Service.getPlacePredictions(Request, function (Results, Status) {     
    ...
});
```

And

```
var Service = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var Request = { address: 'mitskevichi 14', region: 'GE' };
Service.geocode(Request, function (Results, Status) {
    ...
});
```

Combined results from both and get what I initially wanted.

Answer (score 1):

in Google maps documentation there is an example with options like:
`types: ["establishment"]`

I changed it to:
`types: ["address"]`
and autocomplete starts to show all addresses